# jQuery loop, add and remove class

Tags: jquery, loops, fade, slideup

Hi I have a function called after setTimeout, the function is as follows

```
function slideuptwitter(){

    for (var i = 0, limit = 10; i < limit; i++) {
            $('.twitter-article').first().addClass('fade');
            $('.fade').delay( 2000 ).slideUp(5000);
            //$('.fade').appendTo('#twitter-feed');

            //$('.fade').delay( 5000 ).removeClass('fade');

            }

    }
```

This is my layout

```
<div id="twitter-feed">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
<div class="twitter-article">
</div>
```

I wan to grab the 1st twitter article, add the class fade, then after 2 seconds, slide it up.

After this i want to move the fade class to the bottom, remove the class and re-apply the class to the next in line twitter article.

Essentially looping through all 10

The commented out code is the part that is working for me

Thanks for the help

Comment: What isnt working with your code right now? Be more specific

Comment: Sorry, basically right now with the commented code, if i put it back in all the class get set to fade and they all slide up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async recursion: http://jsfiddle.net/7TQCr/2/

```
function fadeOut(elements, callback)
{
    if (elements.length){
        elements.eq(0).addClass('fade');
        elements.eq(0).delay( 2000 ).slideUp(1000, function(){
            elements.eq(0).removeClass('fade');
            fadeOut(elements.slice(1), callback);
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
$(function(){
    fadeOut($('#twitter-feed div'), function(){
        alert("done");
    });
});
```

*Updated to do your specific fade and class requirements.*

### Infinite fadeout/fadein version http://jsfiddle.net/7TQCr/4/:

```
function fadeOut(elements, callback)
{
    if (elements.length){
        elements.eq(0).addClass('fade');
        elements.eq(0).delay( 2000 ).slideUp(1000, function(){
            elements.eq(0).removeClass('fade');
            fadeOut(elements.slice(1), callback);
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
function fadeIn(elements, callback)
{
    if (elements.length){
        elements.eq(0).addClass('fade');
        elements.eq(0).delay( 2000 ).slideDown(1000, function(){
            elements.eq(0).removeClass('fade');
            fadeIn(elements.slice(1), callback);
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
function infinite(){
    fadeOut($('#twitter-feed div'), function(){ 
        fadeIn($('#twitter-feed div'), function(){
            infinite();
        });
    });
}
$(function(){
    infinite();
});
```

Comment: That is amazing, you are a superstar, could this be amended to infinitely loop?

Comment: Of course... Your wish is my command: http://jsfiddle.net/7TQCr/3/ Just comment in the infinite() recursive call (I took it out or it runs forever)

Comment: Thank you, just been looking up, the functions in your code, you have taught me a lot in the space of a few minutes, thanks again